# topological properties of sets $\textit{Iso}(X,d)$ , $\textit{Iso}_{\epsilon} (X,d)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $f:(X,d)\to (X,d)$ be a bijection on metric space $(X,d)$. For $\epsilon>0$ the bijection map $f$ is called $\epsilon$_self_isometry, whenever

$$\sup_{x , x' \in X} \left| d( x,x') - d( f(x), f(x')) \right| \leq \epsilon $$

It is clear that if $f:(X,d) \to (X,d)$ is an isometry (that is $d(x,x')=d(g(x), g(x'))$), then it is an $\epsilon$_self_isometry, for all $\epsilon>0$ .

let $\Pi(X) = X \xrightarrow[onto]{1:1} X$. I defined the metric between $f,g \in \Pi(X)$ as

$$d_{\Pi(X)}(f,g) = \max_{x\in X} d(f(x),g(x)) = d(f(X),g(X)). $$

**Question.** Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.is dense sets $\textit{Iso}(X,d)$ , $\textit{Iso}_{\epsilon} (X,d)$ in $\Pi(X)$.

Comment: $\Pi(X)$ is a space with an improper metric, so it and its subspaces have all topological properties of metrizable spaces. But even with this restriction there is a lot of topological properties which may strongly depend on the metric $d$. Can you specify in which properties you are interested?

Comment: On the RHS of the def'n of $d_{\Pi}$ you should replace $\max$ with $\sup$ as the maximum might not be attained. And then you should replace the whole formula $ F$ on the RHS with $\min (1,F)$  else for some bijections $f,g$ you might have $d_{\Pi}(f,g)=\infty.$